# How to send string array over message port from web application to native applicationand vice versa in Tizen

Tags: ipc, tizen

I have Tizen wearable web application (javascript) and Tizen native service (C/C++). 
I use messageport mechanism to send data between web application and native application. 
If I send simple string value from web to native - everything works fine. But if I try to send string array value - it received not as a string array, but as a string with comma separated values.

For example:
Web application:

```
this._remotePoprt().sendMessage(
        [
         {key: "simple_string_key", value: "simple_string"},
         {key: "string_array_key", value: ["string 1", "string 2"]},
        ],
        this._localPort
);
```

Native application:

```
char* simpleString = NULL;
int result = bundle_get_str(rawMessage, "simple_string_key", &simpleString); 
//OK, simpleString = "simple_string"

int arraySize;
const char** stringArray = bundle_get_str_array(rawMessage, "string_array_key", &arraySize);
result = get_last_result();
//ERROR: result = BUNDLE_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

char* complexString = NULL;
result = bundle_get_str(rawMessage, "string_array_key", &complexString);
//OK: complexString = "string 1,string 2"
```

If I try to send string array from native application to web application, web app does not receives string array values at all.

So question is - is it possible to send string array values from web app to native app and vice versa over message port in Tizen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Initialing the pointer to NULL and the int to 0, which I see in the sample code of Bundle API.

```
 #include <bundle.h>
 bundle *b = bundle_create();
 char *sa = { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };    // A string array of length 3
 bundle_add_str_array(b, "foo", sa, 3); // add a key-val pair

 char **str_array = NULL;
 int len_str_array = 0;

 str_array=bundle_get_str_array(b, "foo", &len_str_array);
 // str_array = { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" }, and len_str_array = 3

 bundle_free(b);
```

You may even try char *a[ ] instead of char **a , though they are same.

Link:

[Bundle API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?langswitch=en&redirect=%2Fdev-guide%2F2.4%2Forg.tizen.native.mobile.apireference%2Fgroup__CORE__LIB__BUNDLE__MODULE.html)

Comment: Everything works fine when I put string array into bundle in native code and then read it from native code. Problem is then I put string array in javascript and try to read this bundle it in native code.

Comment: Could this be the issue of data:[data] or data:data? Please check the comment section of the response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994564/im-trying-to-publish-a-message-of-a-tizen-based-app-on-ros-using-rosbridge-and/40044592#40044592

Answer (score 0):

**Native/Web -> Native**

Okay, In Native message Port, To receive the array from bundle you have to use the  [bundle_iterator_t](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CORE__LIB__BUNDLE__MODULE.html#gaa6b605d88d31645dc691bd88e54baf82), [bundle_foreach](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CORE__LIB__BUNDLE__MODULE.html#gad135a079991ef9ce4fd56aefd729f273), [bundle_keyval_get_array_val()](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CORE__LIB__BUNDLE__MODULE.html#ga042bc41cd198d8342f5257e2a0795b18)  functions. Invoke bundle_iterator_t from message_port_callback.

```
void message_port_cb(int local_port_id, const char *remote_app_id, const char *remote_port,
                      bool trusted_remote_port, bundle *message, 
                      void *user_data){

    bundle_foreach(message, read_data_cb, NULL);

}

int port_id = message_port_register_local_port(local_port, message_port_cb, NULL);

if (port_id < 0)
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "Port register error: %d", port_id);
else
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "port_id: %d", port_id);
```

bundle_keyval_get_array_val() function to catch the array.

```
void read_data_cb(const char *key, const int type, const bundle_keyval_t *kv, 
                  void *user_data){
    void **array_val = NULL;
    int array_len = 0;
    size_t *array_elem_size = NULL;

    if(bundle_keyval_type_is_array(kv)) {
        bundle_keyval_get_array_val(kv, &array_val, &array_len, &array_elem_size);
        // Do Your code
    }

    else {
        bundle_keyval_get_basic_val(kv, &basic_val, &basic_size);
         // Do Your code
    }

}
```

Your data is in array_val.

**Native/Web -> Web**

For sample code similar to this:

```
int ret;

bundle *reply=bundle_create();

char *array[] = {"A","B","C","D"};

bundle_add_str(reply,"test","A");
bundle_add_str_array(reply,"service",array, 4);

ret = message_port_send_message(remote_app_id, remote_port, reply);

if (ret != MESSAGE_PORT_ERROR_NONE)
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, TAG, "message_port_check_remote_port error: %d", ret);
else
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, TAG, "Send message done");

bundle_free(reply);
```

The Structure of the message received on web end would be like :

```
var data =
[
   {key:"test", value:"A"},
   {key:"service", value:["A","B","C","D"]}
];
```

To use the received data, Callback function can be similar to:

```
/* MessagePortCallback instance */
function onReceived(data, remoteMsgPort) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var keyX = data[i].key;
        console.log("key:" + keyX);

        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].value.length; j++){
            var valueX = data[i].value[j];
            console.log("value:" + valueX);        
        }
   }

 }

var localPort = tizen.messageport.requestLocalMessagePort(local_port);
localPort.addMessagePortListener(onReceived);
```

References for details:

[Message Port: Web Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/application-management/application-data-exchange/message-port)

[Message Port: Web API Reference](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/messageport.html)

[Message Port: Native Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/application-management/application-data-exchange/message-port)

[Message Port: Native API Reference](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__MESSAGE__PORT__MODULE.html)

[Native Bundle API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CORE__LIB__BUNDLE__MODULE.html)

That's all for now.